# Cognitive control tasks

Tags: cognitive-psychology, self-control, executive-function

What are the tasks that can be employed to measure cognitive control of an individual (proactive and reactive control). I have read about [AX-CPT task](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236868333_Dual_mechanisms_of_cognitive_control_in_bilinguals_and_monolinguals) [1]. In this task, they use letters. But I am looking for a non-linguistic task.

How about the use of:

1. antisaccade task
2. double step task
3. stop-signal task
4. go/no-go task?

Can we use these tasks to measure proactive and reactive inhibition? If so, how do we do that? I am looking for a task that uses eye-tracking method.

Are there any papers that measure proactive and reactive inhibition and how they are employed using these tasks? Especially, studies comparing monolinguals and bilinguals.

### Also, I wanted to know how we can manipulate the antisaccade task to measure both proactive and reactive inhibition.

[1] "Dual mechanisms of cognitive control in bilinguals and monolinguals" by Morales et al.

Comment: Welcome! This seems like a good question. If you include a reference to where you read about the AX-CPT task it would be even better! Furthermore, could you edit to elaborate why this task did not suit your needs so people answering have some impression of which ones might be more suitable for your study? Depending on how many cognitive control tasks there are, a full exhaustive list might not be within the scope of this site (although I do expect review papers or something similar to be out there).

Comment: AX-CPT can be done with any image; it does not depend on language.

Comment: are there any papers? The letters correspond to language, right?

Comment: Seems like @user18231 is right; [first hit on google](http://pages.wustl.edu/dualmechanisms/axcpt-task#axbackground): _"The most common variant uses LETTER stimuli; however, other variants have also been commonly used (such as the Dot-Probe or DPX)."_ Would a concrete variant of this test using something different than letters answer your question? (Also, notice how important it was to add that additional information about linguistics? ;p)

Comment: Is it possible to use stop-signal task OR go/no-go task OR double step saccade task to measure proactive and reactive inhibition? If so, how to do that? Are there any papers?

Comment: @Christina You can edit your question to include why you believe these tasks might be suitable  and include the question on literature on them in relation to proactive and reactive control.

Comment: @Christina thank you for putting so much effort into your first question! It's now an awesome and clear question. +1